# Save for loop output in python

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist

I develop a code that assess national code. in my algorithm i need to multiply position number in number, so sum this value.
for example: my national code is 0123456789 and I wanna multiplication by 3 (position number) in 2(the number itself).

code : 0123456789
position number* number itself= value
10*9=90
9*8=72
8*7=56
7*6=42
6*5=30
5*4=20
4*3=12
3*2=6
2*1=2
1*0=0

my problem is in sum values . how can do it ?

my code:

```
ID= str(input('ID Number: '))

if len(ID)>10 or len(ID)<8  :
    print('Error')

if len(ID)==8 :
    ID=str('00'+ID)
    print(ID)
elif len(ID)==9 :
    ID=str('0'+ID)
    print(ID)


for i in range(0,(len(ID))):
    x=ID[i]
    y=10-i
    ar=[x,y]
    gg=int(ar[0])*ar[1] 
    print(x,y,gg)
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking: either the objective or the algorithm details.  Please find someone locally who can help you write the needed English.  Alternately, post this to the Stack Overflow site in a comfortable language.

Comment: @Prune  To more understand, I gave an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, this one liner should work:

```
answer = sum([int(ID[i])*(i+1) for i in range(len(ID))])
```

This is equivalent to:

```
answer = 0
for index in range(len(ID)):
    answer += int(ID[index])*(index+1) # since index starts from 0
```